# How to edit .ai or .eps file without illustrator with photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, eps

How to edit .ai or .eps file without illustrator. I have photoshop only on my system. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You could use inkscape.

Comment: You could use CorelDRAW

Answer (score 2):

**It isn't possible to edit .Ai & .EPS files in Photoshop**. However, they can be edited in other programs, such as Inkscape (which is free).

If you have to work on them, and you can't install any other programs on your computer, then you must remake the work using the paths in Photoshop and/or the text.

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you can't **edit** .ai or .eps with Photoshop, those are both vector file formats.

You can open them by using File > Open but it opens it with all objects merged, therefore you can't actually edit it since PS is for raster graphics. You can simply view it.

In order to edit those files you need a vector editing software and while Illustrator is one of them, you've got other ones in the comments above too.

You should also read:

> What is a vector image

Vector images, alternatively, allow for more flexibility. Constructed using mathematical formulas rather than individual colored blocks, vector file types such as EPS, AI and PDF* are excellent for creating graphics that frequently require resizing.

Your company logo and brand graphics should be created as a vector and saved as a master file so you can use it with smaller items such as your business card and letterhead, but also on larger surfaces, such as your corporate jet.

*A PDF is generally a vector file. However, depending how a PDF is originally created, it can be either a vector or a raster file.  Whether you opt to flatten the layers of your file or choose to retain each one will determine the image type.

> What is a raster image

Raster images use many colored pixels or individual building blocks to form a complete image. JPEGs, GIFs and PNGs are common raster image types. Almost all of the photos found on the web and in print catalogs are raster images.

Because raster images are constructed using a fixed number of colored pixels, they can’t be dramatically resized without compromising their resolution. When stretched to fit a space they weren’t designed to fill, their pixels become visibly grainy and the image distorts.

This is why altered photos may appear pixilated or low resolution. Therefore, it is important that you save raster files at precisely the dimensions needed to eliminate possible complications.